# Is this to code (light fixture under outdoor porch roof)

Tags: electrical

Are all components required to be weather resistant under an outdoor overhang? My understanding is that it’s considered a “damp location,” but it’s not clear to me what components are allowed. Is FlexMC allowed? Is this metal box allowed?

[image: wide shot of porch]

[image: closeup of light fixture]

Comment: I'd be concerned about the box the light string plugs into (properly GFCI protected? has an "in use" cover), and even more, about the damage the roots of that tree right next to the house might be doing to the foundation. Roots already seem to be causing the cinder-block fence in the background to crack. (ain't I a barrel of joy this morning?)

Comment: @FreeMan Yeah the box for the string lights will be an in-use box. And I agree about the tree. Fortunately this is a detached garage, and I’ll burn that bridge when I come to it. The inspector wasn’t too worried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First that is a damp location but that looks like EMT or another type of conduit possibly nm but yes conduit is allowed in that location.

The shallow KO box is also allowed in that location things would be different if in a wet location but under that overhang it is code compliant

I would be more concerned with the festoon lighting string being in the drip zone of the roof is that string UL listed?

Comment: Yeah, the strip is UL listed, completely overmolded, and the housing seals against the bulb when it's seated. It's these: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hampton-Bay-Outdoor-Indoor-48-ft-24-Socket-Plug-in-Filament-LED-S14-Edison-Bulb-Black-String-Light-SL48-182-FIL-HD/317458447

Comment: I can't find specific language for MC regarding damp locations, only for wet locations. But if a KO box is okay in a damp location, it seems regular MC should be too, no?

Comment: Rick the code segment you want is 330.10.A. MC is ok most places , Indoors or outdoors, and also direct burial (wet location). the only prohibited wet /damp areas are embedded in plaster, brick or masonry even this can be allowed with a corrosion resistant jacket. , I hope this info helps.

Comment: Ah, okay. I looked at that but wasn’t sure it allowed damp. It does say it can be used outdoors (3); in dry locations (10); in wet locations if jacketed (11). I did email Southwire and they said their "Armorlite Type MC is a compliant for dry locations only." So, I don't think I can use that kind, at least.

Comment: You are correct if the mfg instructions state something different we have to use those even if code allows, the differences in MC aluminum or galvanized “tin” is what makes the difference that I know of today.